# simple_xml parser error with quotation marks in xml, even with CDATA

Tags: xml, simplexml, php

I'm reading XML with `simplexml_load_string()` from array (from database).

Everything is fine until the XML contains quotation marks, simplexml starts to report XML parse errors.

1. I changed `"` into `&quot;` in the XML-file --> parser-error.
2. I escaped the `"` in the XML like `\"` --> parser-error.
3. I used `'` instead of `"` --> everything fine, but I want `"` !
4. So I included the part with the `""` into `CDATA` --> parser-error again!`

XML-snippet:

```
<prepare var="%vorfall%" label="Bezeichnen Sie den Vorfall">
    <![CDATA["Vorfall beim Reiten..."]]>
</prepare>
```

PHP-snippet:

```
$rxml=simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($test['tsValues']));
```

errors - with `&#34;`instead of `"`:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 16: parser error : attributes construct error in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_testcenter/testcenter.php on line 97

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <prepare var=""Unfall beim Reiten, Rocky geht durch"" label="Bezeichnen Sie den in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_testcenter/testcenter.php on line 97

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_testcenter/testcenter.php on line 97

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 16: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag prepare line 16 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_testcenter/testcenter.php on line 97

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <prepare var=""Unfall beim Reiten, Rocky geht durch"" label="Bezeichnen Sie den in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_testcenter/testcenter.php on line 97

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_testcenter/testcenter.php on line 97
```

UPDATE: checked again, problem is happening here - PHP:

```
$txml=file_get_contents("$path_test/".$test['tbTestFile']);
$rxml=simplexml_load_string($test['tsValues']);

// replacing parts of $txml with content containing the famous "" from $rxml 
foreach ($rxml->xpath('//prepare') as $prep) {
    $txml=str_replace($prep['var'],$prep,$txml);
} 

$txml=simplexml_load_string($txml); // this is line 97
```

Comment: TIP: escaping in html/xml has NEVER used backslashes, it's always used character entity encoding. `"` => `&quot;` would be a proper "escape".

Comment: Your example works fine: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k60-d7z so maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @michi: The error is not *as you describe it in question*. I do not mean you don't have a problem, however, with the information provided, there is nothing wrong. The only wrong thing I can see is that you're using `utf8_encode` because the XML in question is properly encoded for SimpleXML already.

Comment: @fab: nice online-tool... but the `CDATA`-part is not in the dump :-(

Comment: @michi check this please: http://www.php.net/simplexml.examples-errors - Provide all errors *you* get.

Comment: @hakre you were right... see edit in question

Comment: michi, please provide your solution as an answer and accept it then (you can't accept it immediately  but after some hours). That will mark the question as solved (and is accepted practice here). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`&quot;`, `CDATA` and `&#34;` do work with simplexml as intended.

My mistake: the code replaced a substr `%vorfall%` within a xml-file. This substring occured within the text of a node (replacement ok) and within an attribute `var="%vorfall%"`. 
The parse-error happened when the attribute had double `""`: `var=""some-replaced-content""`.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the quots for their XML equivalent entity: `&#34;`

```
str_replace('"', '&#34;', $xml);
```

Comment: same problem, unfortunately :-(

Comment: solved it, had nothing to do with the '"' in a strict sense, but thanks for the `&#34;`!